# EJS web application in iframe no login possible

Tags: javascript, authentication, iframe, ejs, session-cookies

I'm currently facing a challenge with my EJS web application when trying to run it within an iframe. Despite various attempts and solutions found online related to cookies and third-party issues, I'm unable to log in successfully. Whenever I try to access the panel, it seems like I'm not logged in, and I keep getting redirected to the homepage.

Here are some extracted code from my police panel projet:

**session.config.js**

```
const app = require("../app"); const mongoose = require("mongoose"); const session = require("express-session"); const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

app.use( session({ secret:
      "korogigtijEEJJjuhJHHjnHBNGJIURH8U763890O9IU8Y4GHBNFNNFJHBFHRUJKG", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, cookie: { httpOnly: false, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15,
    }, store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection, ttl: 60 * 60 * 24 * 15,
    }),   }) );
```

**secure.config.js**

```
exports.ensureAuthentification = (req, res, next) => { if (!req.isAuthenticated()) { res.redirect("/erroraccessdenied"); else { next();   } };

exports.ensureNotAuthentification = (req, res, next) => { if (!req.isAuthenticated()) { next(); else { res.redirect("/erroraccessdenied");   } };

exports.ensureSharePolice = (req, res, next) => { if (req.user.role === "ADMIN_GRADE_SADMIN") { next(); else if ( req.user.role === "USER_GRADE_POLICE" || req.user.role === "USER_GRADE_HG"   ) { next(); else { res.redirect("/erroraccessdenied");   } };
```

**passport.config.js**

```
const app = require("../app"); const passport = require("passport"); const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy; const { findPerId, findPerUserName } = require("../queries/users.queries");

app.use(passport.initialize()); app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => { done(null, user._id); });

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => { try { const user = await findPerId(id); if (user) { done(null, user);
    } catch (e) { done(e);   } });

passport.use(   "local", new LocalStrategy(async (pseudo, password, done) => { try { const user = await findPerUserName(pseudo); if (user) { const match = await user.comparePassword(password); if (match) { done(null, user); else { done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
        } else { done(null, false, { message: "User does not exist" });
      } catch (e) { done(e);
    }   }) );
```

**policepanel.controller.js**

```
const { agentsQuery } = require("../../queries/agents.queries"); const { getRankLSPD, getRankBCSO, getRankSAHP } = require("../../queries/hours.queries");

exports.displayPolicePanel = async (req, res, next) => { try { const users = await agentsQuery(); const agents = users.filter(value => { return value.role === "USER_GRADE_POLICE" || value.role === "USER_GRADE_HG"
    })

let ranklspd = await getRankLSPD(); ranklspd = ranklspd.sort((a,b) => { return Date.parse(b.createdAt) - Date.parse(a.createdAt)
    })

const path = req.originalUrl; res.render("policepanel", { isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(), currentUser: req.user, path, ranklspd, agents
    }) catch (error) { next(error)   } };
```

**policepanel.js**

```
const express = require("express"); const router = express.Router(); const { displayPolicePanel } = require("./policepanel.controller");

router.get("/", displayPolicePanel); module.exports = router;
```

I've tried adding the sameSite: 'none' and secure: true attributes to the cookie in the hope that it would resolve the issue, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. Even in a regular browser session, after successfully logging in, I'm redirected to the homepage as if I'm not logged in.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights you might have regarding this issue.

When logging, I should be redirected to /policepanel and not /accueil (homepage) but when I have a look, both cookies are filled with the session id:

[Cache browser showing both cookies are filled with the session id in F12 dev menu of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbfuS.png)

Thanks